# Kibana and elasticsearch using docker-compose

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I'm trying to use elastic 8 with kibana, with docker-compose,
Everything looks ok, but when I try to access the address, http://localhost:5601 never accesses, always gives error
my kibana log

> [2022-09-16T13:08:00.456+00:00][INFO ][node] Kibana process configured
> with roles: [background_tasks, ui]
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.276+00:00][INFO ][http.server.Preboot] http
> server running at http://localhost:5601
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.298+00:00][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Setting
> up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.319+00:00][WARN ][config.deprecation] The default
> mechanism for Reporting privileges will work differently in future
> versions, which will affect the behavior of this cluster. Set
> "xpack.reporting.roles.enabled" to "false" to adopt the future
> behavior before upgrading. [2022-09-16T13:08:05.420+00:00][INFO
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.428+00:00][INFO ][plugins.taskManager]
> TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID:
> 350923ec-543d-463d-bb32-b74fd558e284
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.465+00:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config]
> Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent
> sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set
> xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the
> bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.465+00:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config]
> Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is
> not recommended. [2022-09-16T13:08:05.477+00:00][WARN
> ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for
> xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being
> invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the
> kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.477+00:00][WARN ][plugins.security.config]
> Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is
> not recommended. [2022-09-16T13:08:05.480+00:00][WARN
> ][plugins.encryptedSavedObjects] Saved objects encryption key is not
> set. This will severely limit Kibana functionality. Please set
> xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the
> bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
> [2022-09-16T13:08:05.489+00:00][WARN ][plugins.actions] APIs are
> disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing
> encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey
> in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command

.

and my docker-compose file

```
  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: "service_healthy"
      es02:
        condition: "service_healthy"
    image: "kibana:8.4.1"
    hostname: "kibana"
    container_name: "kibana"
#    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      SERVERNAME: "kibana"
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "https://es01:9200"
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: "kibana_system"
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: "${KIBANA_PASSWORD}"
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES: "config/certs/ca/ca.crt"
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
    volumes:
      - "certs_data:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs"
      - "kibana_data:/usr/share/kibana/data"
    networks:
      - "elk_network"
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding to `kibana: environment:`

`SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0`

You also should modify your ":" by "=" for the environment variables, that's the syntax for ***docker-compose.yml*** (as I've seen).
So it should now be :

```
  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: "service_healthy"
      es02:
        condition: "service_healthy"
    image: "kibana:8.4.1"
    hostname: "kibana"
    container_name: "kibana"
#    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      SERVERNAME="kibana"
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="https://es01:9200"
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME="kibana_system"
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD="${KIBANA_PASSWORD}"
      ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES="config/certs/ca/ca.crt"
      SERVER_HOST=0.0.0.0
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
    volumes:
      - "certs_data:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs"
      - "kibana_data:/usr/share/kibana/data"
    networks:
      - "elk_network"
```

You can also create a kibana.yml file in which you would write your environment variables.

In this case, it would be `server.host: 0.0.0.0`, check the kibana documentation for syntax compatibility.

You can check this link : [Install Kibana with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html#environment-variable-config) that precise the compatibility.

Also, if you use a config file, make sure to specify it in volumes:.